# how to apply css to multiple line class selector

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, sass, less

how do you apply a specific `css` to `second-page`

## HTML

```
<div className = "section-header second-page">SOME MESSAGE</div>
```

Assuming the above:

## CSS

```
.section-header {
  background-color: black,
}
```

i want to apply a different background color specifically to `second-page` that does not modify `section-header`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the styling to apply to any element with `.second-page` class you should use:

```
.second-page {
  backgound-color: red,
}
```

If you want the styling to apply only to `.section-header` elements that also have `.second-page` class, then you should use:

```
.section-header.second-page {
  backgound-color: red,
}
```

When there's no space between two classes, it means it refers to an element with both classes.

For more information on CSS selectors, please check
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML should be:

```
<div class="section-header second-page">SOME MESSAGE</div>
```

Your CSS could be:

```
.second-page {
  background-color: black,
}
```

You can mix multiple classes within the HTML or target them separately.

If you need to validate your HTML code you can use this free service:
https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: I missed the react tag sorry :-)